# Let $A,B\in M_{n\times n}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, If $A$ is Not Invertible prove that $AB$ and $BA$ aren't invertibles?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Let $A,B\in M_{n\times n}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, If $A$ is Not Invertible prove that $AB$ and $BA$ aren't invertibles?**

**Proof for $AB$:**

Assume by contradiction that $AB$ is invertible, then there is C such that:
$\left(AB\right)C=I_{n}\stackrel{\text{Association}}{\iff}A\left(BC\right)=I_{n}$

Which means $A$ is invertible from the right in contradiction to $A$ not being invertible .

***I need help with proving for BA***

**Note.** I can't use det and other advanced concepts

Comment: Can you not use the exact same argument but left-multiply by the assumed inverse?

Comment: Do the same but multiplying by $C$ *on the left*.

Comment: Can you explain how it helps? 
I get that $(CA)B=I_n$ but how it contradicts that $A$ is not invertible?

Comment: No.  You will have $ C (BA) = I $ and $ (C B) A = I $

Comment: Oh right! don't know why I got confused. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it does. Next time please look for duplicates before asking.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Suppose $BA$ is invertible. Then, there exists a matrix $D$ such that $$(BA)D = D(BA) = I$$
but then,
$$(DB)A = I$$
implying that $A$ is left-invertible, a contradiction.

Comment: Please don't rush to answer such a FAQ. Rather search (and vote to close) for (multi!)duplicates.

Comment: @AnneBauval Sure! I'll keep this in mind. Thank you.